# Remove second price from frontend display

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules, tierprice

Ok so I have a few products that have tier pricing enabled for, the thing that is annoying me is that on the product catalog page when I click the category that it's in it has 2 prices displayed.

For example I have one product with 3 tiers of pricing.  Say $40 is the normal price, $35 if you buy 2 of them, and $25 if you buy 3.  On the category page it would show $40 on top and $25 underneath that.  How do I remove the $25 dollar price and just keep the main price?

Comment: Do you have this live? Do you mind giving the link so I can quickly help you with code?

Comment: As of right now I just put it live, were still testing and have yet to add real products.  http://www.radsupplements.com

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Let's take Hyper Potion product as example :
There is two price : `60.00$` and `15.00$`

If I understand well you want to remove `15.00$`. 
Why don't you use CSS for that ?

> skin/frontend/default/ves_hitech/css/style.css line no 1499

```
.minimal-price-link { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Catalog page: Just use jQuery and hide the second price. I hope you have the price inside some div or span, if not you will have to wrap it around div with some ID.

Product page: I would recommend you use jQuery for that. And attach events on quantity if it's 1, hide other tiered pricing, if customer selects 2 quantity display $35 and hide other two prices etc.

Try this code in your `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file just before the end of li tag inside foreach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(jQuery('#product-price-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> .price').html()) 
    jQuery('#product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: What's the reason for jQuery? Prototype is perfectly capable of hiding items.

Comment: @Fooman I think most of the website now use jQuery right? As he is talking about frontend, I recommended jQuery. No offense by not telling prototype JS :)